# how to apply tween motion on UIcomponents in flex using actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tween

hello i want to apply tween motion on UIcomponents using actionscript in flex.

i searched alot but didn't find something useful help required.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below creates a move tween for a button in actionscript.
Clicking anywhere on the screen will move the button to that location.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" click="moveButton(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.effects.Move;

            private function moveButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var myMove:Move = new Move();

                myMove.target = myButton;
                myMove.xTo = event.stageX;
                myMove.yTo = event.stageY;
                myMove.play();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button id="myButton" />

</mx:Application>
```

For a more advanced example you could look at the Flex documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createeffects_3.html
It shows an example how to extend and use the TweenEffect class to create your own effect class.

Answer (score 0):

Caurina Tweener: http://code.google.com/p/tweener/